# Parallel predict

Tags: r, parallel-processing, predict

I am trying to run `predict()` in parallel on my Windows machine. This works on smaller dataset, but does not scale well as for each process new copy of data frame is created. Is there a way how to run in parallel without making temporary copies?

My code (only few modifications of [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/parallel-r-model-prediction-building-and-analytics/) original code):

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

fit <- lm(Employed ~ ., data = longley)
scale <- 100
longley2 <- (longley[rep(seq(nrow(longley)), scale), ])

num_splits <-4
cl <- makeCluster(num_splits)
registerDoSNOW(cl)  

split_testing<-sort(rank(1:nrow(longley))%%num_splits)

predictions<-foreach(i= unique(split_testing),
                     .combine = c, .packages=c("stats")) %dopar% {
                       predict(fit, newdata=longley2[split_testing == i, ])
                     }
stopCluster(cl)
```

I am using simple data replication to test it. With `scale` 10 or 1000 it is working, but I would like to make it run with `scale <- 1000000` - data frame with 16M rows (1.86GB data frame as indicated by `object_size()` from `pryr`. Note that when necessary I can also use Linux machine, if this is the only option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `isplitRows` function from the `itertools` package to send only the fraction of `longley2` that is needed for the task:

```
library(itertools)

predictions <-
  foreach(d=isplitRows(longley2, chunks=num_splits),
          .combine=c, .packages=c("stats")) %dopar% {
    predict(fit, newdata=d)
  }
```

This prevents the entire `longley2` data frame from being automatically exported to each of the workers and simplifies the code a bit.